# can not change satp.mode in supervisor mode of RISCV64

Tags: riscv

I'm trying to implement virtual memory of a kernel under RISC-V64 (Sv39 mode) with allwinner d1 and OpenSBI, but fail to change satp. the code stop to

```
csrw satp, t1
```

and entire code is here

```
    # set MODE to SV39 （8）
    li t0, 8
    slli t0, t0, 60
    # Right shift the address in the t1 register by 12 bits to get the PFN
    li  t1, 0x80000000
    srli t1, t1, 12
    # Combine MODE and PFN
    or t1, t1, t0
    # Set the satp register to SV39 mode, and set the page table base address at the same time
    csrw satp, t1
    # Execute the sfence.vma instruction to flush the TLB
    sfence.vma x0, x0
```

if I use the following code to write the satp.mode to 0x0, the satp.ppn can be changed.

```
    li t3, 0x80050000
    csrw satp, t3
```

if read the satp ,the result will be 0x000000000050000.

so, why the satp.mode can not be changed.